# HTML CSS Unordered List for Pedigree. How to make it display in IE8 consistent with firefox?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, html-lists

I am creating a table-like by using html unordered nested list, style-up with css to make it look like table. Now it looks exactly how I want in [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7mrG.png), but looks horrible in [IE8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpGSt.png).
 (Sorry that I don't have enough reputation to post the image to show you the differences, kindly refer to code below).

HTML code as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    TODO write content
</div>
<ul>
    <li>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="title">
            My Categories
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            My Categories
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">
                Fun
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                Fun
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="title">
                    Sport
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    Sport
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="title">
                        Surfing
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        Surfing
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="title">
                        Extreme knitting
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        Extreme knitting
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="title">
                    Friends
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    Friends
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="title">
                        Gerald
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        Gerald
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="title">
                        Gwendolyn
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        Gwendolyn
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="title">
                Work
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                Work
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="title">
                    Reports
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    Reports
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="title">
                        Annual
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        Annual
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="title">
                        Status
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        Status
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="title">
                    Trips
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    Trips
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="title">
                        National
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        National
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="title">
                        International
                    </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        International
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: normal;
    min-width: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    background: #e6e49f;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.title {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.description {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: medium;
}
li,
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul {
    line-height: 38em;
    position: relative;
}
ul ul {
    line-height: 18em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0;
}
ul ul ul { line-height: 8em }
ul ul ul ul { line-height: 3em }
ul li { position: relative }
```

I tried to research a lot about CSS for week on this issue and thinking that "line-Height" is the issue because it looked awkward in IE8. I studied that IE8 version should be able to cater the unordered List issue.

Anyone can provide me some idea how to solve this? Or any thing I can used to replace the "line-height"?
I still want to remind unordered listed(`<ul>`) with css only, no `<div>` because I don't want to change the core file of cakephp.

Comment: Why dont you just use a table for this?

Comment: First make sure you have a doctype and your html is valid so that the browser goes into standards mode. When posting html you can make it easier for us by posting a link with your code from http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ryan Murphy: Actually I am using cakephp-TreeBehavior to build the tree. It's dyanmic and might have different depth.

Comment: ZippyV: Thanks for your info. signing up now.

Comment: note that people are [not likely to read all that code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/183101).

Comment: @EliranMalka true, but its simple enough code tho

Comment: Ryan Murphy: I missed the doctype and added the doctype, and now it's working. Thank you so much for your info.

Comment: @EliranMalka: Sorry that I am noob and don't know about jsfiddle.net before this. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @jason Please answer your own question. Here, on StackOverflow we do not add tags like [SOLVED] into the title. Answer your question (see the button) and accept it as answer. Please read the FAQ to understand how this site works.

Comment: @bažmegakapa - I can't answer it but after 8 hours as I am new member. I will answer it after 8 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ZippyV reminded me to declare the `<!DOCTYPE>` on it by simply add a line of code
    
before the `<html>` tag, so that the browser goes into standards mode and the html is valid.

Now IE8 display it exactly the same as firefox.